# Checking for file existence in a local domain

Tags: javascript, url

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out since there are numerous examples of how to do this and none seem to work for me the way they are suppose to. I want to check for the existence of a local file. I have placed a file in the same directory as the html code and it is accessible and readable. This is NOT a URL or permission problem. Here is one example of code I am trying to use. checkURL() is called with the URL in the global variable linkURL.

```
function doesFileExist(urlToFile)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status != "200") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkURL()
{
  var result = doesFileExist(linkURL);

  if (result == true) {
       alert("Exists");
       // Page would be loaded here with window.location.href = linkURL;

  } else {
      alert("NOT Exists");
  }
}
```

The problem is this will always return true but never returns false and never alerts "NOT exist" Somehow it just bypasses that alert code. I have tried many variations of this and in all cases when the URL does not exist the test fails to display anything but always works when it exists.  My goal here is to access multiple local URL's and display those that exist but if one does not exist I want to be able to display a message to that effect to the user and not actually access the URL and get a page error. The files and HTML code will ultimately be on a DVD and accessed by a browser.

Comment: local domain .. so, you're serving it using some sort of http server, correct?

Comment: which browser are you testing on ... works fine, even with `file:///` protocol (which you'll be using if it's on a "DVD") in firefox ... chrome doesn't play well with requests to `file:///` resources unless you specify a particular flag on the command line (which I don't know off hand but will do the search for you if you can't find out yourself) ... IE/Edge ... who knows what they'll do

Comment: No server. I am directly accessing it with FF (waterfox) browser and yes to a properly formed URL to a file in the same directory as the code. It does work. It does load the PDF if it exists assuming the load command is in there. As shown in this code it displays an alert that it exists. The problem is as I stated it does not display anything if the file does not exist unless you try to actually load it and then you get a firefox file not found page. This code is not made up by me. It is from examples on stackoverflow and elsewhere that are suppose to work.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: I was thinking that after your last message. I should have checked. Well the object here is to learn. Anyhow yes the error is : NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

Comment: Which happens only when the file does not exists. I fixed it this way which seems to work at least for Firefox. other browsers need to be checked. I really don't care about Chrome though just FF and Explorer.                                                                                                      'code'      function doesFileExist(urlToFile)
{
try {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
      xhr.send();
      if (xhr.status = "200") {
          return true;
      }
    } 
catch(err) 
    {
         return false;
    }  
}

Comment: OK obviously I don't know how to enter code here but you get the point - use try around the code return true if file exists and catch error and return false if it does not.